# cucumber -Parameterize browser at run time without using Testng or hardcoding data from Feature files Parallely

Tags: selenium, cross-browser, cucumber

Aim : Parallel execution of browsers passed at run time in cucumber

Confusion : Don't want to use Testng along with cucumber [Avoiding Parameters tag in Testng.xml] since @Before[Cucumber api] and @parameters{testng}is causing Extent reports invidually for each feature

Code: 
In Hooks i have :

@Before

```
public void ScenariosetUp(Scenario scenario) throws Exception {
this.scenario = scenario;
        Log.startLog("Start of Test cases ");
        **TPBaseSteps.openBrowser();**

    }

TPBaseSteps class :  
    public static WebDriver openBrowser() throws Exception {

        String browserName = JsonReader.RetrieveTestDataFromExcel("browserConfig", "Browser");

        log.info("Chosen browser is " + browserName);
        if (!grid) {
            switch (browserName.toLowerCase()) {
            case "chrome":
                log.info("Launching Browse as  : " + browserName);
                WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
                driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
            case "firefox":
                log.info("Launching Browse as  : " + browserName);
                WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
                driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
                break;
```

}

Issue: I am passing a singular value from Excel which RetrieveTestDataFromExcel reads and passes on to below code , But i want to achieve it for multiple browsers , I have grid setup so if i can get parameters in this method then i will run them parallely.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the approach for Ruby:

You can use the cucumber.yml as the controller here. 
cucumber.yml

```
BROWSERS = IE,Chrome,Firefox
```

Accessing the browsers from Hooks

```
 puts ENV['BROWSERS']
```

Hope this will be helpful. Let me know if you need any more information on this approach.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, We shall understand Cucumber was created as a way to overcome ambiguous requirements and misunderstandings, targeting both non-technical and technical members of a project team, but if someone think Cucumber is a testing tool then we are wrong.

Data Parameterization shall flow from Feature File to Step implementation methods. So Cucumber does not provide such parameterization option directly in one go in hooks.

The only thing can be done to implement your scenario would be by following tagged hooks.

```
Feature File :- 3 Scenarios

@Chrome 
Scenario: This is First Scenario running on chrome browser
 Given this is the first step
 When this is the second step
 Then this is the third step

@Firefox 
Scenario: This is Second Scenario running on firefox browser
 Given this is the first step
 When this is the second step
 Then this is the third step

@IE
Scenario: This is Third Scenario running on ie browser
 Given this is the first step
 When this is the second step
 Then this is the third step

@Before("@Chrome")
    public void beforeFirst(){
        Log.startLog("Start of Test cases ");
        TPBaseSteps.openBrowser("Chrome");
        System.out.println("This will run only before the chrome Scenario");
    } 

@Before("@Firefox")
    public void beforeSecond(){
        Log.startLog("Start of Test cases ");
        TPBaseSteps.openBrowser("firefox");
        System.out.println("This will run only before the firefox Scenario");
    } 

@Before("@IE")
    public void beforeThird(){
        System.out.println("This will run only before the ie Scenario");
    }

 TPBaseSteps class :    
 public static WebDriver openBrowser(String browserName) throws Exception {

        log.info("Chosen browser is " + browserName);
        if (!grid) {
            switch (browserName.toLowerCase()) {
            case "chrome":
                log.info("Launching Browse as  : " + browserName);
                WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
                driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
            case "firefox":
                log.info("Launching Browse as  : " + browserName);
                WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
                driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
                break;
```

Or Pass Chrome | FF | IE as parameter in Scenario/Scenario Outline and get the parameter value in step implementation method. But in this case, open browser shall not be invoked in hook but its not advisable as per my understanding.

Hope it helped you.